# How to extract certificate from a Radius sniffertrace containing EAP

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, radius

I am looking for a way using programming in Python to extract from a Radius sniffertrace the EAP packetflow, which includes e.g the Server Hello and therfore Server certificate.
So far I am using tschark to extract the Radius packet containing EAP Server hello with the fragments already reassembled. I can store this packet in PDML format. There I can see all the Bytes of the certificate. 
Lets say, I woulde be able to build the String/List of Bytes from the certificate. 
Question: How could I build now from all those Bytes e.g a DER or PEM formated certificate file?

In wireshark GUI the certificate can be saved as Extraktes Bytes in DER format manually, but I need the certificate automattically extracted using some Python programming.
http://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/201003/msg00080.html

Thx for your valid input!

Answer (score 0):

Just to update. I am using now tshark to create PDML and extract with python code using ElementTree the certificate bytes which I convert to ASCII allow to save the certificate as DER file.

- extract the certificate bytes in a string : cert_string_bin
- change the bytes into ASCII

cert_string_der = cert_string_bin.decode("hex")

- write the certificate file in DER format

cert = open("server_cert_of_stream_" + str(stream_counter )+".der", 'w')

cert.write(cert_string_der)

cert.close()

Comment: If that answers your question, please accept your own answer.